# warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

Tags: c++, c

I have a piece of software I am trying to get to work. It was written in 2008 & I have fixed many of the issues, but still have many occurances of this one. I have searched & searched, but am not finding any pertinent answers.
Here is the code section:
/* APPS */

```
aa = 0x80c4b8;

/* Engine Speed */

bb = 0x80e6dc;

/* Manifold Pressure */

cc = 0x80b330;

/* Torque */

dd = 0x80ecbc;

printf("Enter name of log file: ");

fgets(tbuf, 30, stdin);

OF = fopen(tbuf,"w+");

if(OF == NULL) {
    printf("Error creating file\n");
    return(-1);
    }

printf("\n\n");

fprintf(OF,"SCI Memory Read Log file\n");
fprintf(OF,"Acc\tRPM\tMAP\tTQ\n",aa,bb,cc,dd);
```

Can anyone help on this? I am not even a novice at coding & have fixed 14 pages of warnings, down to a page of this style warning. I am pretty sure that this is C++, but am not positive.
Thank you,
Ed

Comment: This looks like plain C, there's nothing strictly C++ about this. As for your error, the last line looks like the culprit.

Comment: Where are the specifiers in `fprintf` check this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/

Comment: Good that as a 1st time poster, you had compiler warnings enabled.  Amazing how many do not. +1

Comment: Compiler warnings were in the Makefile that came with this. Unfortunately, the author is not available to help.

Comment: Posting the declaration of variables `aa,bb,cc,dd` would help provide a definitive answer.

Comment: The variables are right in the code. I have that part all fixed & just need to figure 1 more warning & it should compile. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

In this line, you are passing `aa, bb, cc, dd` and your format string `"Acc\tRPM\tMAP\tTQ\n"` is not expecting any arguments

```
fprintf(OF,"Acc\tRPM\tMAP\tTQ\n",aa,bb,cc,dd);
```

I think what you want is

```
fprintf(OF,"Acc 0x%x\tRPM 0x%x\tMAP 0x%x\tTQ 0x%x\n",aa,bb,cc,dd);
```

If the values are `unsigned long int` then

```
fprintf(OF,"Acc 0x%lx\tRPM 0x%lx\tMAP 0x%lx\tTQ 0x%lx\n",aa,bb,cc,dd);
```

notice that the specifier `%x` prints the hexadecimal representation of an `unsigned int`, and `%lx` is for `unsigned long int`.

Comment: I will give that a try right now & see if it compiles. Thank you very much. Ed

Comment: I just tried adding that & got " warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
  fprintf(OF,"Acc 0x%x\tRPM 0x%x\tMAP 0x%x\tTQ 0x%x\n",aa,bb,cc,dd);" 4 times, for the 4 spaces I put it in. So, no go on that. I do thank you for trying, though. Ed

Comment: Could it need some form of deliminator (,./\) between the Acc & 0x%x? I have been searching the site that shan posted for a couple days & still really do not understand it too much.

Comment: @yankneck696 It appears that you are writing this data to a file, so it's up to you. What data do you want the file to contain. I updated the answer.

Comment: Perfect, that line compiled correctly. I will do the rest & see what happens. Thank you, very much, iharob !!!!

Comment: Well, with adding a few variables that were missing, I got all of those errors to "Make". Now, I have a ""‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument"" error. Should I start a new thread to keep it clean on the forum, or continue it here. I did search it, but did not find it. Thank you very much for all of your help.Ed

Comment: Ok, so please read [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) it is the Linux manual for `printf`.

Comment: THank you, I will try to figure this one out on my own. I thank you very much.

Comment: I got everything working & would like to thank you all for your assistance.iharob, you were instrumental to me. I now need some bardware bits & get to work.

Comment: @yankneck696 I'm very glad my answer was useful, have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).